# Why is the following series $\sum_{(n,m)=1}1/n$ divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose $m$ is a some positive integer. I want to show that $\sum_{(n,m)=1}1/n$ is divergent. I wanted to use integral test but it is not monotone decreasing. Is there any other way?

Comment: Your sigma notation is unclear to me.

Comment: gcd(n,m)=1 i.e (n,m)=1

Comment: This is OK, but what is the summing index and it goes from where to where and what is the summand?

Comment: @DrZafarAhmedDSc The sum is taken  over all positive integers $n$ relatively prime to $m$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: The sum includes the terms $\frac 1 {km+1}$ for every positive interger $k$ and $\sum _k \frac 1 {km+1}=\infty$.